Incorrect format problem when converting a BMP image file from Base-64 to binary
I am trying to convert the Base-64 data contained in the "data" returned by toDataURL of a fabric.Canvas into a file with its corresponding extension (BMP). The result is a "The file is not in the correct format" error.
The steps I follow are the following.

I get the dataURL variable from the fabric.Canvas with the toDataURL method.
dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
format: 'bmp',
quality: 1.0
});

I extract only the string that contains the "data".
dataURLto64 = dataURL.substr(dataURL.lastIndexOf(',') + 1,
dataURL.length -
dataURL.lastIndexOf(',') - 1);

The above is done on the client. On the server I needed to save the string in segments in a TXT text file. I have verified that the final content of the text file is identical to the original dataURLto64 (in Base-64).

I extract the content of the text file.
string strtextfile64 = File.ReadAllText([path]);


I convert that string into a byte array with the method Convert.FromBase64String


byte[] fileBinary = null;
fileBinary = Convert.FromBase64String(strtextfile64);
        
File.WriteAllBytes([path], fileBinary);

I have verified that both, dataURLto64 and strtextfile64 have the same characters and the same number.
To verify that the Base-64 string is correct, I have included the following verification on the server.
 int mod4 = strtextfile64.Length % 4;   

 if (mod4 > 0) {
    strtextfile64 += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
 }

It was not necessary to modify strtextfile64 because mod4 = 0.
I am attaching two text files in which the initial (client) and final (server) Base-64 strings are contained.
Inicial cliente
Final servidor
Could someone tell me the reason why that Base-64 data converted to binary data does not comply with the original BMP format from the original BMP file created from the fabric.Canvas?
Edit to add the client code that I am using to transfer the image file to the server.
CLIENT
I make a send with Ajax that when it receives the response from the server with the file name data and the last position of the character sent, the sending is repeated as long as the last position does not exceed the length of the string.
async function exportarCanvasF1(nombrearchivo, start_) {       

let start = Number(start_);
        var chunkSize = 90000; // size of each chunk
        let start_limite = (start == 0 ? Number(start_) : 

Number(start_)) + chunkSize;      

 if (start_limite > dataURL.length) {
     start_limite = (start_limite - (start_limite -  dataURL.length - 1));
  }
 if (Number(start) + chunkSize > dataURL.length) {
    chunkSize = chunkSize - ((Number(start) + chunkSize) - dataURL.length) + 1;           }
            
  let dataURL_;
    
   if (Number(start) < dataURL.length) {           

   dataURL_ = dataURL.substr(start, chunkSize);
   dataURL_ = encodeURI(encodeURI(dataURL_));
               
   $.ajax({
                

   type: "POST",
   url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: 

'{"parametro":"funcion","valor":"TroceadoFileBase64","tabla":"' + dataURL_ + '","campo":"' + nombrearchivo + '","criterio":"' + start_limite + '","v1":""}',
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (devolucion) {
     if (devolucion.d) {
       var d = JSON.parse(devolucion.d);
       exportarCanvasF1(d[0][1], d[1][1]);
           }
    },
     error: function (req, status, error) {
                    }
                });
     }
  else if (!Number(start) < dataURL.length) {
      dataURL_ = dataURL.substr(start, chunkSize);
      console.log("Length chunk: " + dataURL_.length);
      dataURL_ = encodeURI(encodeURI(dataURL_));
                
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: '{"parametro":"funcion","valor":"TroceadoFileBase64","tabla":"' + dataURL_ + '","campo":"' + nombrearchivo + '","criterio":"' + start_limite + '","v1":""}',
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (devolucion) {
         if (devolucion.d) {
            var d = JSON.parse(devolucion.d);
                 $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: '{"parametro":"funcion","valor":"TroceadoFileBase64_fin","tabla":"' + nombrearchivo + '","campo":"","criterio":"","v1":""}',
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (devolucion) {
                     if (devolucion.d) {
                                    }
                     },
                      error: function (req, status, error) {                                    
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (req, status, error) {
                     alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
                    }
                });
    
            }
        }

SERVER
The parameters "parameter", "value", "table", "field", "criterion" are used in a routine to supply a method on the server.
The method performs the following.
 public string TroceadoFileBase64(string base64file, string nombrefile, string start)
        {
    string jsonDevolucion = "";
           
   string base64filedec = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(base64file);  
   string base64filedec1 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(base64file);  
                                                                               
    byte[] b = null;
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding codificador = new 
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    b = codificador.GetBytes(base64filedec1);

    CrearfiledesdeArray(b, nombrefile);

     string[,] devolucion = new string[2, 2]; // 2 bloques de 2 datos                
                devolucion[0,0] = "nombrefile";
                devolucion[0,1] = nombrefile;
                devolucion[1,0] = "start";
                devolucion[1,1] = start;
                
     jsonDevolucion = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(devolucion);

     return jsonDevolucion;
}
               
public string TroceadoFileBase64_fin(string nombrefile)
        {
               
                string strtextfile = File.ReadAllText((string)HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + Left(nombrefile, nombrefile.Length - 4) + ".txt");

                int mod4 = strtextfile.Length % 4;
                if (mod4 > 0)
                {
                    strtextfile += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
                }

                byte[] b = null;

                b = Convert.FromBase64String(strtextfile);

                File.WriteAllBytes((string)HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + nombrefile, b);

                return "Finalizado";
        }

public void CrearfiledesdeArray(Byte[] array, string nombrefile)
        {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream((string)HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + Left(nombrefile, nombrefile.Length - 4) + ".txt", FileMode.Append);
                fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Dispose();
          
        }
       

TroceadoFileBase64 method writes each chunk to the text file; the TroceadoFileBase64_fin method is called only at the end and extracts the text and converts it to binary.

Your issue appears to stem from the fact that fabric.Canvas does not natively support exporting images in BMP format. While the toDataURL method allows you to specify a format (e.g., png, jpeg), the 'bmp' format is not actually supported in most browsers and JavaScript environments. This is likely why your Base64 data cannot be decoded into a valid BMP file — the initial data itself is not in BMP format.
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js?tab=readme-ov-file

Thanks for your help Daryush. So that is surely the problem. I will have to convert beforehand.

Your two files are different.  One of them has + characters and one of them has spaces.  Maybe encodeURIComponent is needed before transmitting the strings.

Thank you James! Thanks for reviewing the files and comparing them. However each data string has been processed on the client with encodeURIComponent. I always do it twice, that is: encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(string));
I have tried with a JPG file and now the file is created and can be opened with Paint, but it is completely blank

Sorry James. I mistakenly deleted the vote for your comment. I'm really sorry!

No worries.  Something is being incorrectly encoded/decoded imo.  You'd need to show the client and server code for transmitting/receiving the file (fetch operation).

Edited and added the client code

encodeURI isn't going to work (it does not encode + among other things).  Use encodeURIComponent instead, just once should be sufficient.

It's true, my intention was to use encodeURIComponent but I was wrong.
Curiously now with encodeURICOmponent only once the Ajax sending gives an error. However with encodeURI twice no.

The project is ASP.NET. I need the image file to be sent after the user has made edits to the fabric.Canvas. The file must come from fabric.Canvas.

Finally everything worked correctly. Using encodeURIComponent once is enough. The Ajax submission error was caused by the length of each chunk being excessive. I have left chunks of 30,000 characters and the transfer is done in almost a second.
Thank you all very much for your answers and help.

The client code that has finally worked with the help of the colleagues who have responded is the following
I get the dataURL variable from the fabric.Canvas with the toDataURL method. Now is with JPG file.
dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({ format: 'jpg', quality: 1.0 });

I extract only the string that contains the "data".
dataURL = dataURL.split(',')[1];

Function in the client.
async function exportarCanvasF1(nombrearchivo, start_) {       
        
        let start = Number(start_);
                var chunkSize = 30000; // size of each chunk
                let start_limite = (start == 0 ? Number(start_) : 
        
        Number(start_)) + chunkSize;      
        
         if (start_limite > dataURL.length) {
             start_limite = (start_limite - (start_limite -  dataURL.length - 1));
          }
         if (Number(start) + chunkSize > dataURL.length) {
            chunkSize = chunkSize - ((Number(start) + chunkSize) - dataURL.length) + 1;           }
                    
          let dataURL_;
            
           if (Number(start) < dataURL.length) {           
        
           dataURL_ = dataURL.substr(start, chunkSize);
           **dataURL_ = encodeURIComponent(dataURL_);**
                       
           $.ajax({               
        
           type: "POST",
           url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: 
        
        '{"parametro":"funcion","valor":"TroceadoFileBase64","tabla":"' + dataURL_ + '","campo":"' + nombrearchivo + '","criterio":"' + start_limite + '","v1":""}',
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (devolucion) {
             if (devolucion.d) {
               var d = JSON.parse(devolucion.d);
               exportarCanvasF1(d[0][1], d[1][1]);
                   }
            },
             error: function (req, status, error) {
                            }
                        });
             }
          else if (!Number(start) < dataURL.length) {
              dataURL_ = dataURL.substr(start, chunkSize);
              console.log("Length chunk: " + dataURL_.length);
              dataURL_ = encodeURIComponent(dataURL_);
                        
               $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: 
                '{"parametro":"funcion","valor":"TroceadoFileBase64","tabla":"' + 
                dataURL_ + '","campo":"' + nombrearchivo + '","criterio":"' + 
                start_limite + '","v1":""}',
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (devolucion) {
                 if (devolucion.d) {
                    var d = JSON.parse(devolucion.d);
                         $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         data: '{"parametro":"funcion","valor":"TroceadoFileBase64_fin","tabla":"' + nombrearchivo + '","campo":"","criterio":"","v1":""}',
                         dataType: "json",
                         success: function (devolucion) {
                             if (devolucion.d) {
                                            }
                             },
                              error: function (req, status, error) {                                    
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (req, status, error) {
                             alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
                            }
                        });
            
                    }
                }

And the server:
public string TroceadoFileBase64(string base64file, string nombrefile, string start)
        {
    string jsonDevolucion = "";
           
  
   *tring base64filedec1 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(base64file);  
                                                                               
    byte[] b = null;
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding codificador = new 
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    b = codificador.GetBytes(base64filedec1);

    CrearfiledesdeArray(b, nombrefile);

     string[,] devolucion = new string[2, 2]; // 2 bloques de 2 datos                
                devolucion[0,0] = "nombrefile";
                devolucion[0,1] = nombrefile;
                devolucion[1,0] = "start";
                devolucion[1,1] = start;
                
     jsonDevolucion = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(devolucion);

     return jsonDevolucion;
}
               
public string TroceadoFileBase64_fin(string nombrefile)
        {
               
                string strtextfile = File.ReadAllText((string)HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + Left(nombrefile, nombrefile.Length - 4) + ".txt");

                int mod4 = strtextfile.Length % 4;
                if (mod4 > 0)
                {
                    strtextfile += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
                }

                byte[] b = null;

                b = Convert.FromBase64String(strtextfile);

                File.WriteAllBytes((string)HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + nombrefile, b);

                return "Finalizado";
        }

public void CrearfiledesdeArray(Byte[] array, string nombrefile)
        {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream((string)HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + Left(nombrefile, nombrefile.Length - 4) + ".txt", FileMode.Append);
                fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Dispose();
          
        }

Here you finally see the JPG image opened with the Paint program.

I clarify that there are variables in the methods provided that belong to complementary routines in my project and that I have not exposed them so as not to extend the thread. They correspond to both the client and the server.

Changes in Logic
Encoding Method:

Original: Used encodeURI twice.
Change: Replaced encodeURI with encodeURIComponent to ensure the Base-64 data is correctly encoded for safe transmission. encodeURIComponent encodes all characters that have special meaning in a URI, ensuring the data remains intact.

Data Transmission Format:

Original: Data was sent as a concatenated string.
Change: Used JSON.stringify to construct the data object for the AJAX request. This ensures that the data is correctly formatted as JSON, which is more robust and less prone to errors during transmission.

File Writing Process:

Original: Used FileStream without proper resource management.
Change: Added a using statement for FileStream to ensure that the file stream is properly closed and resources are released after writing the byte array. This prevents potential file access issues and ensures data integrity.

Updated Client-Side Code with Comments
async function exportarCanvasF1(nombrearchivo, start_) {       
    let start = Number(start_); // Convert start_ to a number
    var chunkSize = 90000; // Size of each chunk
    let start_limite = (start == 0 ? Number(start_) : Number(start_)) + chunkSize; // Calculate the limit for the current chunk

    if (start_limite > dataURL.length) {
        start_limite = (start_limite - (start_limite - dataURL.length - 1)); // Adjust the limit if it exceeds the dataURL length
    }
    if (Number(start) + chunkSize > dataURL.length) {
        chunkSize = chunkSize - ((Number(start) + chunkSize) - dataURL.length) + 1; // Adjust chunk size if it exceeds the dataURL length
    }
            
    let dataURL_;
    
    if (Number(start) < dataURL.length) {           
        dataURL_ = dataURL.substr(start, chunkSize); // Extract the current chunk from dataURL
        dataURL_ = encodeURIComponent(dataURL_); // Encode the chunk to ensure safe transmission
               
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                parametro: "funcion",
                valor: "TroceadoFileBase64",
                tabla: dataURL_,
                campo: nombrearchivo,
                criterio: start_limite,
                v1: ""
            }), // Send the chunk to the server
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (devolucion) {
                if (devolucion.d) {
                    var d = JSON.parse(devolucion.d); // Parse the server response
                    exportarCanvasF1(d[0][1], d[1][1]); // Continue sending the next chunk
                }
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                console.error("Error during AJAX request:", error); // Log any errors
            }
        });
    } else if (!Number(start) < dataURL.length) {
        dataURL_ = dataURL.substr(start, chunkSize); // Extract the final chunk
        console.log("Length chunk: " + dataURL_.length);
        dataURL_ = encodeURIComponent(dataURL_); // Encode the final chunk
                
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                parametro: "funcion",
                valor: "TroceadoFileBase64",
                tabla: dataURL_,
                campo: nombrearchivo,
                criterio: start_limite,
                v1: ""
            }), // Send the final chunk to the server
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (devolucion) {
                if (devolucion.d) {
                    var d = JSON.parse(devolucion.d);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            parametro: "funcion",
                            valor: "TroceadoFileBase64_fin",
                            tabla: nombrearchivo,
                            campo: "",
                            criterio: "",
                            v1: ""
                        }), // Notify the server that the transfer is complete
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (devolucion) {
                            if (devolucion.d) {
                                console.log("File transfer completed successfully."); // Log success message
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (req, status, error) {
                            console.error("Error during final AJAX request:", error); // Log any errors
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez."); // Alert if no response from server
            }
        });
    }
}

Updated Server-Side Code with Comments
public string TroceadoFileBase64(string base64file, string nombrefile, string start)
{
    string jsonDevolucion = "";
    string base64filedec = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(base64file); // Decode the Base-64 string
    byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(base64filedec); // Convert the Base-64 string to a byte array

    CrearfiledesdeArray(b, nombrefile); // Append the byte array to the file

    string[,] devolucion = new string[2, 2]; // Create a 2x2 array for the response                
    devolucion[0, 0] = "nombrefile";
    devolucion[0, 1] = nombrefile;
    devolucion[1, 0] = "start";
    devolucion[1, 1] = start;
                
    jsonDevolucion = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(devolucion); // Serialize the response to JSON

    return jsonDevolucion; // Return the JSON response
}

public string TroceadoFileBase64_fin(string nombrefile)
{
    string strtextfile = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nombrefile) + ".txt"); // Read the entire text file

    int mod4 = strtextfile.Length % 4;
    if (mod4 > 0)
    {
        strtextfile += new string('=', 4 - mod4); // Add padding if necessary
    }

    byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(strtextfile); // Convert the Base-64 string to a byte array

    File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + nombrefile, b); // Write the byte array to the final file

    return "Finalizado"; // Return a completion message
}

public void CrearfiledesdeArray(Byte[] array, string nombrefile)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nombrefile) + ".txt", FileMode.Append))
    {
        fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length); // Append the byte array to the file
    }
}


Thank you very much Seven for your code simplification.
